# NSFetchedResultsController: don't refresh each new cell

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've noticed that insertion of data with a `NSFetchedResultsController` in `Core Data` would refresh each cell in my `Table View` using the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

My application starts by fetching 100+ items from a Web Service. When they are added to the Core Data Database, a `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` call is made for each cell. I expect only the first 8-9 visible cells to refresh. How can I change that? The reason why this is a problem is that my application is downloading the cover image first time the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called -- and when it is called for each cell, this is not a optimal solution.

**EDIT1:**
My code is fully based on an example from the [CS 192p course at Stanford University](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/). I've downloaded their `Photomania.zip` from lecture 14 and just inserted the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method which displays the items name in the log when the method is called. You can grab my code here: http://uploads.demaweb.dk/Photomania.zip.
As you will see, it looks like this method is called for each item in the table? Why?

**EDIT2:**
I was using this method in my `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` from the iOS Developer Library. I found out that the `withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade` cause it to both call the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `willDisplayCell` for each cell. When changing it to `withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone` only the visible cells are called.

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you reusing your cells (i.e. providing a cell reuse identifier)?

Are you implementing the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods that will allow your view controller to insert/remove rows as they come "online" instead of doing a `[tableView reloadData]`? Within those methods you should be using '`[UITableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:]`, `[UITableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimations:]`, etc. to adjust the referenced rows.

Finally, you might move your image loading logic into the `UITableView` delegate method `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` instead. That way it is only be invoked when it is actually about to be displayed.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` protocol and it is implemented almost like the documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html.

Is it normal, that the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate will make a `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` when all the data becomes available?

Thank you for the notice about `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`. That will probably solve my problem, but I still thing it is unusual that the cell method is called for each cell.

Comment: `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` didn't work. Please see my EDIT1.

Comment: With the `NSFetchedResultsController` there is only two ways your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` will get called, when you explicitly invoke `reloadData` on your tableView or when you insert/delete rows/sections in response to the delegate calls. You need to monitor via the debugger those areas in the code to see what is causing a full table reload. `NSFetchedResultsCoordinator` in no way interacts directly with the table view itself.

Comment: Could the problem be, that each time a new record is added to Core Data, the complete table is reloaded? For me that is unexpected behaviour since it should only refresh the visible records.

Comment: The table won't reload unless you explicitly tell it to do so. As far as I know, when inserting a new row, it only has to request the one cell (if it is visible), or any other cell made visible by the insertion, but not the whole table. However, if you have variable height rows, then it will have to recalculate the table size row by row.